# setUserdata is not defined but if I console.log the data it is there

Tags: reactjs

I am following along some React tutorials but I get `uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: setUserdata is not defined`. If I console.log(res.data) I get:

```
age: 66
count: 135975
name: "tom"
```

So I am not sure why I cannot setUserdata(res.data). Any pointers appreciated.  Code is below.

```
import './App.css';
import Axios from "axios"
import {useEffect, useState} from "react"

function App() {

  const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);

  const fetchUserData = ( () =>{
    console.log(userName)
    Axios.get(`https://api.agify.io/?name=${userName}`).then((res)=>{
      console.log(res.data);
      setUserdata(res.data);
      //console.log(res.data);
    })
  }); 

  const handleNameChange = (event) =>{
    setUserName(event.target.value)
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input 
        placeholder="eg Richard"
        onChange={handleNameChange}
      />
      <button onClick={fetchUserData}>Predict Age</button>
      <p>{userName}</p>
      <h1>Name {userData?.name}</h1>
      <h1>Age{userData?.age}</h1>
      <h1>Count {userData?.count}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo. Instead of `setUserdata(res.data)` use `setUserData(res.data)`